# How to give final QT app to my client

Tags: c++, macos, qt, netbeans

I am new to Qt. I have created an Qt application in netbeans on OS X now I want to hand over it to client but when I open the exe it also open terminal with it. How can I give it to user so it just shows the GUI.

Comment: .exe? You mean .app? Add more information on how you build and deploy your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create application bundle that contains your application and all needed frameworks and libraries. Appication bundle is a directory with ".app" suffix and has next structure:

```
AppName.app
    Contents
        MacOS
        Frameworks
        Resources
        ...
```

Simple steps to deploy your application into bundle:

1. Create AppName.app directory
2. Create Contents/MacOS subdirectory into AppName.app
3. Copy executable file into AppName/Contents/MacOS directory
4. Run "macdeployqt AppName.app" in terminal
5. Your bundle is ready. You can run it in Finder

More information: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html